# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession

Tags: apache-spark

When I use the command below:

```
spark-submit --master spark://hadoop01:7077 --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi 
/data/spark-2.2.0-binhadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar
```

The error happens.

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession

My Hadoop environment is hdp 2.4.0.0-169. How can I fix the error?

Comment: ~/.bash_profile: export PYTHON_HOME=/home/spark/anaconda3
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=$PYTHON_HOME/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=$PYSPARK_PYTHON
export PYSPARK_PYTHONPATH_SET=1
export SCALA_HOME=/data/scala-2.11.8
export SPARK_HOME=/data/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export HDP_VERSION=2.4.0.0-169
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client
export PATH=$PATH:$PYTHON_HOME/bin/
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin

Comment: spark-env.sh:export JAVA_HOME=/data/jdk1.8.0_111
export SCALA_HOME=/data/scala-2.11.8
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client

export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=idanluexactdata51
export SPARK_LAUNCH_WITH_SCALA=0
export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars

export SCALA_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/scala-2.11.8/lib
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=18080
export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=$SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native
export SPARK_CONF_DIR=/data/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf

Comment: If I change the hdp folder name to 2.4.0.0,and change the HDP_VERSION=2.4.0.0，the problem is solved, but I can't change the folder name.Has other way to solve the problem?Thank you.

Comment: did you try exporting with inverted commas like `export HDP_VERSION="2.4.0.0-169"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your jar is missing a "-"

```
/data/spark-2.2.0-binhadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar
```

should be

```
/data/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar
```

unless that is a typo in your submission. If a typo in submission please post the full input and error properly formatted.

Comment: I am a noob.,Thank you help me.

Comment: I find the org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession in the spark-sql_2.11-2.2.0.jar in /data/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars.So I guess I don't put the spark_class_path in the environment.

Comment: but I already write "export SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars" in the spark-env.sh.So I can't understand why the error happen

Comment: God bless me,I solve the problem.the spark in my server has two version.I use spark-submit by spark1.6.0.So I cd the spark2.2.0's bin, then execute ./spark-submit,the problem solved.

Comment: sorry I couldn't be of more help. Glad you figured it out!